# Why does electromagnetic induction occurs only when the conductor cuts the magnetic field lines

Tags: electromagnetism

Greeting

I know the field of electromagnetism is not yet fully clarified but I wonder if there is an idea,theory Why does electromagnetic induction occur only when the conductor cuts the magnetic field lines. 
[image]

Comment: When else would it happen?

Comment: I don't understand the question – what else would you expect? If there's no magnetic field, then there can't be magnetically induced induction, right? Also, not that the figure shows only a few of the lines that these two magnet poles would induce, and that the "Induced emf" is a totally wrong label – without a current in the rod, there's no electromagnetic force happening here, and furthermore, how does the arrow point at a force?

Comment: The longer I look at that figure, the more confusing/wrong it gets.

Comment: "I know the field of electromagnetism is not yet fully clarified", um I think that was sorted out more than 150 years ago (Maxwell's equations) aside from quantum effects, too. So, I'm really not sure what you're talking about. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: In any case, the question of "how does this physical phenomenon happen" would belong on a physics site, not an engineering side, too.

Comment: Marcus Müller  1 Did you read the question 2  If there's no magnetic field, then there can't be magnetically induced induction if you have eyes in the picture are permanent magnets 3 maxwell equations are not proved they are an abstract model 4 when I'm already writing to teach you what electromagnetic induction is Electromagnetic induction (or sometimes just induction) is a process where a conductor placed in a changing magnetic field (or a conductor moving through a stationary magnetic field) causes the production of a voltage across the conductor.

Comment: @loltor 1) yes 2) permanent magnets  don't  induce currents by themselves 3) how can you say any physical equation is ever proven? All the physical theory we build is designed to align with Maxwell, because Maxwell has shown to describe what we observe *extremely* well. That's as close as you (philosophically) can ever get to a proof in physics 4) exactly, and that's why *permanent* magnets don't induce an electrical field over a conductor (the voltage or current is a result of that, not the cause).

Comment: @loltor Electromagnetic induction occurs when there is **change** in the magnetic flux through an area (not necessarily a conductor) which produces electric field. If you are asking why it produces electric field maybe this would help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/284261/why-does-a-changing-magnetic-field-produce-a-current

Comment: you do not understand  
what changing magnetic field mens  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FehUCQKKRwo

Comment: you have hundreds of similar videos, so look at all the literature

Comment: you will not find any other explanation

Comment: In each book about electrical engineering we talk about is a process where a conductor placed in a changing magnetic field (or a conductor moving through a stationary magnetic field writers of these books are idiotic and you are smart

Comment: how can you argue that some theory is correct one of the greatest physicists of the day does not know how to do poles repel and unlike poles attract http://lesswrong.com/lw/99c/transcript_richard_feynman_on_why_questions/

Comment: Actually, all this makes a lot of sense when you realize that a magnetic field can be treated as the result of the speed of light limiting the speed at which electric fields from electric charges at one location move through spacetime to affect charges elsewhen. Stop thinking of a magnetic field as anything other than a consequence of relativity.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around.

We observe that sometimes when a conductor is moved within a magnetic field, it generates an EMF, and sometimes it doesn't.

Then more careful observation shows that when it moves parallel to field lines is when it doesn't generate a voltage, and when it cuts across field lines it does.

So then we say 'voltage when it cuts field lines' to summarise what we observe.

Then we can get quantitive, and find how much voltage gets generated for what field gets cut how fast.

Unfortunately, these summaries and equations don't actually tell us what's going on, or why.

If you get down into quantum mechanics, then you start getting explanations of what could be happening at the magnetic field level. Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why quantum mechanics. You've just shifted the goalposts.

If it helps, a better summary of what's going on would be a loop of wire surrounds a certain amount of magnetic field, and it generates a voltage when the amount in the loop changes, either by the loop changing size (cutting lines of field), or by the field changing strength (like in a transformer).

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic lines of Force Field, B and Magnetic Flux Field, H are present when current flows thru a conductor.

When released instantly , the current resists a change by inducing a large electric field transient V=LdI/dt. While current may  now rapidly decay while V rapidly increases momentarily usually causing an arc when switched from contacts according to an L/R time constant until the extinguishing voltage is reached by some gap.

So in summary , a Magnetic Field H created when energized proportional to current and may be time varying or DC until released then that creates a larger Electric Field pulse , E which lasts for a brief time.  The total energy stored in the inductor is being released when this current is cut instantly from the conductors  and is released in the air between contacts in the form of a spark.  Semiconductor diodes can normally suppress this with diodes to the opposite supply rail or through some RC snubber.

Answer (score 0):

Even at slow rates of movement, the Lorentzian transformation describes how the relativistic warping of vectors will lead to "retarded" potentials, aka delayed potentials, of what occurred some tiny fraction of time ago. Faraday and Maxwell used "lines of flux" to describe the relations of the 3_D vectors.